# WPF: Converter default value before DataContext set

Tags: c#, wpf

Now I am working with WPF. My Controls visibility binded like in here:

```
<Button Content="Click me!" Visibility="{Binding Path=SomePath,  Converter={StaticResource MessageCloseConverter}}"/>
```

This works after `DataContext` is setted. But when I run project first time `DataContext` is `null` and Visibility is Visible.I want set visibility collapsed first time and after setting `DataContext` converter should work like now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `FallbackValue` property:

```
<Button Content="Click me!" Visibility="{Binding Path=SomePath,  Converter={StaticResource MessageCloseConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>
```